# How to separate parameters from a list based on certain conditions?

Tags: list-manipulation, differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, filtering

The following codes create a table of parameters Br and Dr based on corresponding parameters b and c. How to separate/divide the list/table of Br and Dr for which corresponding b or c are negative against b and c both are positive?Thanks in advance.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
tstar = -5;
ode1 = y'[t] == -Sin[x[t]]/y[t];
ode2 = x'[t] == -Cos[x[t]] (6 Sin[x[t]] Cos[x[t]] + y[t] (b - c (1 + 3*y[t]^2)))/(2*
   y[t]^3*(b + c (y[t]^2 - 1)));
ode3 = v'[t] == -(b + c*(y[t]^2 - 1))/(4*y[t]*Cos[x[t]]) + Sin[x[t]]/(2*y[t]^2);
bc = {x[tstar] == 0, y[tstar] == Br, v[tstar] == Log[Dr]};
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{ode1, ode2, ode3, bc}, {x, y, v}, {t, tstar,0}, {b, c, Br, Dr}]
data = Table[{Br, Dr} /.FindRoot[{(y[b, c, Br, Dr][0] - 1) /. sol, v[b, c, Br, Dr][0] /. sol}, {{b, 1}, {c, 1}}, WorkingPrecision -> 2], {Br, 2.5, 2.7, .1}, {Dr, 20, 30, 1}]
```

Comment: Your code of "Table" is equivalent to: `Table[{Br, Dr}, {Br, 2.5, 2.7, .1}, {Dr, 20, 30, 1}]` Certainly not what you want.

Comment: Yes, that is certainly not what I need. I want to divide this table based on the corresponding values of b<0 or c<0 from the FindRoot. May be conditional argument in data table will work here but not sure how to use it.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want. Can you give an example?

Comment: Dear @Daniel Huber, if u run: data = Table[{b, c} /.FindRoot[{(y[b, c, Br, Dr][0] - 1) /. sol, v[b, c, Br, Dr][0] /. sol}, {{b, 1}, {c, 1}}, WorkingPrecision -> 2], {Br, 2.5, 2.7, .1}, {Dr, 20, 30, 1}] ,you will see some negative values of b ; I just want to see what {Br,Dr} producecs those negative values. Please focus only on last line of my codes.

Answer (score 0):

The output of:

```
Table[{b, c} /. 
  FindRoot[{(y[b, c, Br, Dr][0] - 1) /. sol, 
    v[b, c, Br, Dr][0] /. sol}, {{b, 1}, {c, 1}}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 2], {Br, 2.5, 2.7, .1}, {Dr, 20, 30, 1}]
```

[image]

Note that only the last row of the output contains negative numbers. Therefore, the last row belongs to Br== 2.7 and this produces negative b's.

**Addendum**

If you want to pick {Br, Dr} according to {b, c}, you may use Sow and Reap like:

```
res = Reap[
   Do[t = {b, c} /. 
      FindRoot[{(y[b, c, Br, Dr][0] - 1) /. sol, 
        v[b, c, Br, Dr][0] /. sol}, {{b, 1}, {c, 1}}, 
       WorkingPrecision -> 2]; 
    If[t[[1]] < 0 || t[[2]] < 0, Sow[{Br, Dr}]], {Br, 2.5, 
     2.7, .1}, {Dr, 20, 30, 1}]
   ][[2, 1]]
```

Comment: Actually I want my code will pick it. Can we use some conditional statement so that it will separate {Br, Dr } for wich b or c gets negative ?